# Extending numpy mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to mask a numpy array `a` with `mask`. The mask doesn't have exactly the same shape as `a`, but it is possible to mask `a` anyway (I guess because of the additional dimension being 1-dimensional (broadcasting?)).

```
a.shape
>>> (3, 9, 31, 2, 1)
mask.shape
>>> (3, 9, 31, 2)
masked_a = ma.masked_array(a, mask)
```

The same logic however, does not apply to array `b` which has 5 elements in its last dimension.

```
ext_mask = mask[..., np.newaxis] # extending or not extending has same effect
ext_mask.shape
>>> (3, 9, 31, 2, 1)

b.shape
>>> (3, 9, 31, 2, 5)
masked_b = ma.masked_array(b, ext_mask)
>>> numpy.ma.core.MaskError: Mask and data not compatible: data size is 8370, mask size is 1674.
```

How can I create a `(3, 9, 31, 2, 5)` mask from a `(3, 9, 31, 2)` mask by expanding any `True` value in the last dimension of the `(3, 9, 31, 2)` mask to `[True, True, True, True, True]` (and `False` respectively)?

Comment: This works: `masked_b = ma.masked_array(*np.broadcast(b, ext_mask))`, but I don't know why `ma.masked_array` does no automatic broadcasting. Edit: Maybe because it only wants to store views into two equal sized arrays for efficiency?

Comment: This gives `TypeError: __new__() takes at most 11 arguments (8371 given)`

Comment: Did you pass both arrays to `broadcast`? The error sounds like the *-operator has unpacked the whole big array, rather than a list of two arrays.

Comment: Uh, sorry, my bad! `broadcast` is the wrong function. You need to use `broadcast_arrays`.

Comment: Seems to be working now. I found an alternative `ext_mask = np.empty(b.shape, dtype=bool);  ext_mask[...] = (mask==True)[..., np.newaxis]`. Which one would be better (both seem to produce the same result)?

Comment: "These arrays are views on the original arrays"... seems like your approach is the way to go when one tries to avoid costly memory copy and allocations. Do you want to write this as an answer?

Comment: The documentation says that `broadcast_arrays` returns views into the original arrays, which means no allocations are performed.

Comment: Yes, I'll write an answer, but first I'm going to put a little more research into the topic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives the desired result:

```
masked_b = ma.masked_array(*np.broadcast(b, ext_mask))
```

I have not profiled this method, but it should be faster than allocating a new mask. According to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_arrays.html), no data is copied:

> These arrays are views on the original arrays. They are typically not
>   contiguous. Furthermore, more than one element of a broadcasted array
>   may refer to a single memory location. If you need to write to the
>   arrays, make copies first.

It is possible to verify the no-copying behavior:

```
bb, mb = np.broadcast(b, ext_mask)
print(mb.shape)       # (3, 9, 31, 2, 5) - same shape as b
print(mb.base.shape)  # (3, 9, 31, 2) - the shape of the original mask
print(mb.strides)     # (558, 62, 2, 1, 0) - that's how it works: 0 stride
```

Pretty impressive how the numpy developers implemented broadcasting. Values are repeated by using a stride of 0 along the last dimension. Whow!

**Edit**

I compared the speed of broadcasting and allocating with this code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma

a = np.random.randn(30, 90, 31, 2, 1)
b = np.random.randn(30, 90, 31, 2, 5)

mask = np.random.randn(30, 90, 31, 2) > 0
ext_mask = mask[..., np.newaxis]

def broadcasting(a=a, b=b, ext_mask=ext_mask):
    mb1 = ma.masked_array(*np.broadcast_arrays(b, ext_mask))

def allocating(a=a, b=b, ext_mask=ext_mask):
    m2 = np.empty(b.shape, dtype=bool)
    m2[:] = ext_mask
    mb2 = ma.masked_array(b, m2)
```

Broadcasting is clearly faster than allocating, here:

```
    # array size: (30, 90, 31, 2, 5)

In [23]: %timeit broadcasting()
The slowest run took 10.39 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.4 µs per loop

In [24]: %timeit allocating()
The slowest run took 4.86 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 982 µs per loop
```

Note that I had to increase array size for the difference in speed to become apparent. With the original array dimensions allocating was slightly faster than broadcasting:

```
    # array size: (3, 9, 31, 2, 5)

In [28]: %timeit broadcasting()
The slowest run took 9.36 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 39 µs per loop

In [29]: %timeit allocating()
The slowest run took 9.22 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.6 µs per loop
```

The broadcasting solution's runtime seems not to depend on array size.

Comment: Which array sizes did you use for the two tests?

Comment: (30, 90, 31, 2, x) and (3, 9, 31, 2, x)

Comment: Interesting. Broadcasting doesn't seem to depend on array size too much (if as all). Definitely the better choice - thanks again.